# How to make code ignore a vertically merged column in microsoft word table

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a code that will hide a row within a table in Microsoft Word. The problem is that the table now has a vertical column in it. This macro now cannot work because of a vertically merged column (not allowed to delete it!). I am not entirely sure if there is a way to further manipulate the macro to have it ignore the vertically merged column.

Here is the code to hide the desired row.

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()

   Dim ItemTable1 As Range
   Dim ItemTable2 As Range
      With ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
          Set ItemTable1 = .Rows(9).Range
          ItemTable1.End = .Rows(9).Range.End
      End With

      With ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
          Set ItemTable2 = .Rows(9).Range
          ItemTable2 = .Rows(9).Range.End
       End With

      With ItemTable1.Font
           .Hidden = True
      End With
      With ItemTable2.Font
          .Hidden = True
      End With
  End Sub
```

Image of the table in Microsoft Word. The Row I want to hide is in Green. The Vertical column is creating issues.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because the table has vertically-merged cells, you will need to loop through all cells in the table, testing the RowIndex. For example:

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim Cll As Cell, Rng As Range, r As Long, c As Long
r = 9
With ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
  For Each Cll In .Range.Cells
    With Cll
      If .RowIndex = r Then
        .Range.Font.Hidden = True
        If .ColumnIndex > c Then c = .ColumnIndex
      End If
    End With
  Next
  Set Rng = .Cell(r, c).Range
  With Rng
    .End = .End + 1
    .Font.Hidden = True
  End With
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you know where I can read/about this some more? I don't particularly understand this portion of the code: Set Rng = .Cell(r, .Columns.Count).Range
I get a debugger when its ran saying "requested member of collection does not exist"

Comment: That error suggests you have horizontally-merged or split cells as well. Your screenshot wasn't present/visible when I wrote the code. I've updated the code in the answer to take account of that.